# Can not connect to hbase via phoenix

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper, apache-phoenix

I am trying to connect [hbase](/questions/tagged/hbase) via [phoenix](/questions/tagged/phoenix):
First, I added `phoenix-2.jar` to hbase lib directory.
Then restart region server and then create a project in netbeans and add the `phoenic-2-client.jar` to classpath of the project.
Then added below lines into `hbase.site.xml` for hbase and phoenix.

```
    <property>
<name>hbase.master</name>
<value>23.201.00.100:60000</value>
<description>The host and port the HBase master runs at. 
</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
  <value>2222</value>
  <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
  The port at which the clients will connect.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
         <value>rs1.example.com,rs2.example.com,rs3.example.com,rs4.example.com,rs5.example.com</value>
  <description>Comma separated list of servers in the ZooKeeper Quorum.
  For example, "host1.mydomain.com,host2.mydomain.com,host3.mydomain.com".
  By default this is set to localhost for local and pseudo-distributed modes
  of operation. For a fully-distributed setup, this should be set to a full
  list of ZooKeeper quorum servers. If HBASE_MANAGES_ZK is set in hbase-env.sh
  this is the list of servers which we will start/stop ZooKeeper on.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/zookeeper</value>
  <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
  The directory where the snapshot is stored.
  </description>
</property>
```

My hbase is pseodo distribiuted mode.Finally, I wrote the following code in netbeans to connect to hbase:

```
 Connection conn;
    Properties prop = new Properties();
      try{
        Class.forName("com.salesforce.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver");
        conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:rs1.example.com,rs2.example.com,rs3.example.com,rs4.example.com,rs5.example.com:2222:hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase");
        System.out.println(conn);
```

but shows this error:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 102 (08001): Malformed connection url. jdbc:phoenix:rs1.example.com,rs2.example.com,rs3.example.com,rs4.example.com,rs5.example.com:2222:hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase
    at com.salesforce.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:146)
    at com.salesforce.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver$ConnectionInfo.create(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:206)
    at com.salesforce.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:78)
    at  com.salesforce.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:115)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
    at hbase.phoenix.HbasePhoenix.main(HbasePhoenix.java:30)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Please guide me..

Comment: Please use proper capitalization and indenting. I gave up editing half way.

Comment: did you specify username and password in you xml file or connection url?

Comment: no,i didn't difine username and password.i am not sure the code is correct or not..i dont know what to do this

Comment: have you connected to HBase without phoenix?and what does "hdfs" means in your connection url?or do you have any idea about all these?

Comment: no,i try connect to hbase via jdbc driver but cant find it..i become confused... do you have any suggestion for connectig to hbase that i can do insert,scan,... and processing operation ..i want transform my relation db to hbase.

Comment: hdfs is the value of hbase.rootdir in hbase-site.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Check if this [link](https://github.com/ivarley/jirachi/blob/917d0c77a50be80f7422f22d9deb3362a6b05ae8/src/main/java/com/salesforce/jirachi/ingest/PhoenixUtils.java) helps.

As mentioned in the [Phoenix](https://github.com/forcedotcom/phoenix) project, the jdbc connection url should be like this : `jdbc:phoenix:zookeeper1:port,zookeeper2:port`

By default zookeeper listens at port 2181.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly says, your db connect URL is malformed in `getConnection` method:

```
jdbc:phoenix:rs1.example.com,rs2.example.com,rs3.example.com,rs4.example.com,rs5.example.com:2222:hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase
```

I believe your jdbc connect url should look something like this:

```
jdbc:hbql;maxtablerefs=10;hbase.master=23.201.00.100:60000
```

Comment: i think this connection url is work with hbql but i want to connect via phoenix...please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer for anyone still looking:

Your jdbc connection string must look like:

> **jdbc:phoenix:zookeeper_quorum:2181:/hbase_znode** or
>
> **jdbc:phoenix:zookeeper_quorum:/hbase_znode**

(By default zookeeper listens at **port 2181**.)

**zookeeper_quorum** - Can be comma-separated server-names(must be fully qualified DNS names)
**hbase_znode** - hbase or hbase-unsecured

e.g.

> jdbc:phoenix:server1.abc.com,server2.abc.com:2181:/hbase

Answer (score 0):

I used Phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.1.  If you are running in pseud-distributed mode, you can just do `connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix");` straight away.  Just make sure your java program can communicate with Master, Zookeeper, and RegionServer.  Check what ports and IP/hostname are being used.  In my case (SSH Tunneling), I made sure the ports HMaster:16000, HQuorumPeer:2181, and HRegionServer:16201 wasn't blocked.